# Minimum vertical pipe height under kitchen sink drain

Tags: plumbing, leak, drain, pipe, pvc

Is there a minimum height that the pipe directly under the kitchen sink drain needs to be, before it bends (in my case to the left)?

Here is a picture of what I have (first image), and then a picture of what I want to do (second image).

I would like to make room to put a trash basket under the sink and I don't know if there are any negatives of shortening the vertical pipe height under the sink drain?

[image: first image of what I have]

[image: second image of generally what I want to do]

Comment: The biggest issue I see with your plan is that the extra elbows may slow the flow of food/gunk laden water out of the sink leading to an increased likelihood of clogging. You might consider 2 x 45° instead of 3 x 90° bends to see if that will give you the room you need. I'll presume that A) the trap is out of view off the bottom of the picture, and B) the upslope angle of your proposed drain line is due to your mad Photoshop skillz, not your intended plan ;) (Note that this is a comment, not an answer, because I'm not sure of code requirements.)

Comment: Thank you FreeMan, I’ll look into if the 2 x 45 degree angles work for me, and confirming both your assumptions are correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a minimum you can do what you want. I agree with freeman that it may be prone to clogging or drain a little slower but you can make those changes and see how it works it may be just fine.